# add and show Text "Self" along with bound list items in gridviewcomboboxcolumn vb.net winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview, combobox, telerik

i have created combo box column in RadGridview

```
    Dim dt_Organization As DataTable
    Dim da_Organization As OleDbDataAdapter
    da_Organization = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Organization from PayList_tbl", con)
    dt_Organization = New DataTable("PayList_tbl")
    da_Organization.Fill(dt_Organization)
    Dim PayerList As GridViewComboBoxColumn = New GridViewComboBoxColumn
    PayerList.Name = "Organization"
    PayerList.HeaderText = "Payer"
    PayerList.DataSource = dt_Organization
    PayerList.ValueMember = "Organization"
    PayerList.DisplayMember = "Organization"
    PayerList.FieldName = "Payer" 
    PayerList.Width = 250

    RGV_PaymentPlan.Columns.Add(PayerList)
```

now i want to add "Self" with other Organization Names so that user can select Organization name or Self . when user selects Self i want to enter customer Id into table.

Comment: so i don't see any problem with your thread, you want to do stuff and there's no error and you did not try to do it? how can we help? you add the word "self" to that combobox before adding the list and then you check if combobox index = 0 it means self, that's all

Comment: I've never used that control but, if it's like other bound controls, it just shows what's in the data source. If you expect some extra item to show up in the control, you need to add that item to the data source.

Comment: @OctaCode  thanks for your response .. the problem is when i try to add item with code  "PayerList.items.add "  or PayerList.items.Insert " , it gives error  "Items  is not the member of Gridviewcomboboxcolumn"

Comment: here is the code i tried  but through the error
  Dim dataItem As New RadListDataItem()  
  dataItem.Text = "Self"
  PayerList.Items.Add(dataItem)

Answer (score 0):

Monisa,

If the column is in bound mode, you should add records directly to the applied DataSource, not to add items (RadListDataItem) programmatically. Please have in mind that GridViewComboBoxColumn offers a predefined list of options and these options are considered as valid for the drop down list editor. Hence, you can't add items that are not present in the column's DataSource.

However, if you need allows the users to extend this list, please refer to the following help article which demonstrates how you can implement a scenario in which the end-users are able not only to choose from a predefined list of values represented by RadDropDownListEditor, but to add their own values to that list: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/editors/how-to/allow-end-users-to-add-items-to-dropdownlisteditor

I hope this information helps.